# Fórmula de Excel en Google sheet

Tags: excel, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Me podrían decir por favor por qué esta fórmula de Excel no funciona en Google Sheet

```
=SI([@Paquete]="AVANZADO",CONCATENAR("Quincenal, vence ",TEXTO([@Fin],"dd mmm 
 aaaa")),
 CONCATENAR(TEXTO(FECHA.MES([@[Puesta en línea]],0),"dd mmm aa")," - ", 
 (TEXTO(FECHA(AÑO([@[Puesta en línea]]),MES([@[Puesta en línea]])+ 
 (Tabla253[[#Encabezados],[1]]*[@[Cada x meses]]),DIA([@[Puesta en 
 línea]])-1),"dd mmm aa"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### CONSIDERACIONES

Las referencias estructuradas -@[Paquete], Tabla253[[#Encabezados],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsuwH.png)], etc- son una característica de Excel que Google Sheet a la fecha de este post aún no posee.

En este [enlace - que está en inglés](https://support.dataeverywhere.com/article/27-incompatible-formulas-between-excel-and-google-sheets) también podrás ver que otras fórmulas son incompatibles entre excel y google sheet.

En tal sentido, las referencias estructuradas hay que convertirlas en referencias explícitas, para eso, debes chequear cómo se crean las tablas en excel y su nexo con las [referencias estructuradas y por ende con las referencias explícitas](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/usar-referencias-estructuradas-con-las-tablas-de-excel-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).

### SOLUCION

Asumí los siguientes datos para verificar que la formula con referencias explícitas funcione:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La celda G13 contiene lo que se busca:

```
=+SI(C13="AVANZADO";CONCATENAR("Quincenal, vence ";TEXTO(F13;"dd mmm 
 aaaa"));CONCATENAR(TEXTO(FECHA.MES(D13;0);"dd mmm aa");" - ";
 (TEXTO(FECHA(AÑO(D13);MES(D13)+
 ($B$12*E13);DIA(D13)-1);"dd mmm aa"))))
```

Sólo tienes que reemplazar `;` por `,` dependiendo tus configuraciones y el idioma predefinido en tus servicios de Google. [Cómo cambiar el idioma](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=es-419)

En mi caso como obtuve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
=+IF(C13="AVANZADO";CONCATENATE("Quincenal, vence ";TEXT(F13;"dd mmm 
 yyyy"));CONCATENATE(TEXT(EDATE(D13;0);"dd mmm yy");" - ";
 (TEXT(DATE(YEAR(D13);MONTH(D13)+
 ($B$12*E13);DAY(D13)-1);"dd mmm yy"))))
```

Ten en cuenta que dependiendo donde van a estar tus datos tienes que actualizar tus referencias explícitas.

Comment: dado el contenido y longitud de tus aportes creo que aquí lo ideal hubiera sido que editaras tu primer ayuda y ahi colocaras esto, no veo la necesidad de una doble respuesta

Comment: @element De acuerdo, en particular porque el autor de la pregunta aún no ha "reaccionado"

Comment: @element te entiendo lo tendré en cuenta porque esto podría parecer que genera ruido, aunque personalmente si una publicación ya empezó a ser comentada por diferentes usuarios -como ocurrió en este caso- prefiero hacer uno nuevo para que quede un registro por un tema de transparencia.

Comment: @HubertRonald En este sitio los comentarios deberían ser borrados luego de que han cumplido su propósito y sólo usuarse para sugerir para mejorar o solicitar clarificación, quizás para hacer alguna aclaración provisional para luego integrarla a la publicación, esto último con la finalidad de minimizar el número de revisiones.

Comment: @Rubén, he integrado las respuestas que di, incluyendo la consulta adicional que efectuó user116731 sobre sustituir las referencias estructuradas a explícitas.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien la mayoría de las aplicaciones de hoja de cálculo ofrece exportar/importar archivos de Excel este supuesta compatibilidad es limitada.

En este caso en particular la función de tablas de Excel no es soportada por la Hoja de Cálculo de Google, pero existen características y funciones de hoja de cálculo propias de esta aplicación que podrían darte un servicio similar.

Podrías hacer uso [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=es) la cual te permite usar [Google Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) por ejemplo `=QUERY(A2:E6;"select avg(A) pivot B")`

NOTA sobre el uso de nombres de rango.

En QUERY se puede usar el nombre de rango en el primer argumento, pero los "nombres de campos" sólo pueden ser la letra de la columna, o bien de la forma Col1 cuando el primer argumento es una matriz bidimencional, como sería el resultado de IMPORTRANGE, FILTER, `{}`, por mencionar algunas.

Comment: Complementario a QUERY es que Google Sheet permite [Asignar un nombre a un intervalo de celdas](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) con lo cual se pude emular parte de la características de la tabla de excel `=suma(vector)` donde vector es `A2:A15`

Comment: Quizás algo que no he visto que logre emularse -ni en [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)- de una tabla de excel es que esta permite de forma automática en la fila inmediatamente que le sigue actualizar los campos correspondientes y por ende el tamaño de la tabla, esto se aplica para integrar excel con [Power Apps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/How-to-save-data-from-form-to-excel/td-p/154724) pero ya es algo del propio MS-Microsoft

Comment: Como el asignar nombre a un rango existe en ambas aplicaciones y el funcionamiento es muy diferente a una "referencia estructurada", además de que sólo se puede usar en el primer argumento y no para hacer referencia a las columnas en el segundo, yo no diría que "emula" algo de la tabla de Excel, sin embargo, sí que puede ser útil. Por otro lado, aquí no se trata de comparar aplicaciones sino formas de lograr un resultado determinado mediante un lenguaje/plataforma de programación

Comment: Cuando me refiero a emula -simula- parte de una característica de la tabla de excel digamos dato={2,3,1,2,4} para obtener las frecuencias relativas aplico `=[@dato]/SUMA([dato])` en cambio con asignación de nombre tendría`=celda/suma(dato)`.

Comment: También considero que la comparación no puede ser esquiva, porque estamos hablando de funcionalidades que únicamente la tabla de excel posee a la fecha, como actualizarse automáticamente cuando se le agrega datos, lo cual es útil cuando se trabaja con varias tablas porque ya no se hace necesario estar re-actualizando las fórmulas, aunque no hay que abusar de esta funcionalidad porque los archivos se pueden volver muy pesados, lo que dificulta compartirlos.

Comment: @HubertRonald Mientras la comparación tenga sentido en el contexto de lo que quiere resolver la pregunta, bien. Aquí yo sólo veo que pregunta por las razones por las que no funciona una fórmula, lo demás, está bien para un foro tradicional o un chat aquí el tema sería enfocarlo a solicitar clarificación sugerir cómo mejorar la respuesta a la que se refieren estos comentarios. Por cierto ¿ya conoces la función de chat de este sitio? Como ya tienes más de 100 de rep. podrías abrir una sala, quizás enfocada a discutir estas comparaciones o cualquier cosa relacionada con la temática del sitio...

Comment: ... o sus miembros.

Comment: Excelente @Ruben la verdad no sabia que se disponía de eso aquí y es mejor de esa manera, porque el quid es intercambiar ideas y tener perspectivas diferentes para ampliar lo que ya sabemos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89565/discussion-between-ruben-and-hubert-ronald).